# what is the significance of having a UITextView in a UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have come across many sample codes where the `UITextView` is embedded within `UIScrollView`. However, `UITextView` itself has scrolling properties. So what additional advantage does this set-up i.e `UITextView` within `UIScrollView` provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, when you only want to show text, there is no point of embedding a `UITextView` inside of a `UIScrollView`. But think about a more complex setup, where you might have more view components inside your view, maybe some more buttons, labels, text fields,... All these together need to fit onto a scrollable area, which is why you would use a `UIScrollView` as the container, and then add all the additional views (incl the `UITextView`) to it

Comment: thanks dude. this does makes sense and justifies the use of UIScrollView

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` is a subclass(inherits from) of `UIScrollView` only. [For more info](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITextView).

How do you approach, if you want to display a page of text but you might have only little space in `UIView`?

For ex: You have more than 5 pages of T&C, Can you possible to display in a page of View without scrollable way?

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to achieve this with only UITextView? actually, i don't have a text 5 pages long but atleast large enough to not fit in one screen. and i was able to achieve the scrolling without the UIScrollView